# iOS - get JSON feed in every tableview cell with Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I'm building an iOS app with a table view. I have an array containing ID's that I use to populate the table view. Now I want to do a call to a web service in each table view cell that contains this ID in the URL. I want to use the JSON response to fill the cell with the correct data. I think the data has to be fetched in the background.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how I can do this with Swift? I searched the web but I couldn't find any tutorials about this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/791/steps-to-integrate-uitableview#t=201607231358539622971. Hope it can help.

Comment: Thank you. It's clear to me how I can use tableview. But in this case I want to do a separate API call in each cell. For example, if I have 3 rows in my tableview, then I want to do a different API call (with different URL) in each of these 3 cells.

Answer (score 0):

**I think help full this step for you.**

Step 1 :- Call API service from `viewDidLoad()` function.

Step 2 :- Handle API response and Use one array for store API data

Step 3 :- array count use for `numberOfRowsInSection`

Step 4 :- Use array data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Thank you. It's clear to me how I can use tableview. But in this case I want to do a separate API call in each cell. For example, if I have 3 rows in my tableview, then I want to do a different API call (with different URL) in each of these 3 cells.

Comment: Why you call different api each cell ?

Comment: I populate the tableview with station names. In each cell I have to do a call to the API with that specific station name, to get the departure times async.